# <class=""> in product title on new product type drupal commerce kickstart

Tags: 7, commerce

I created a custom product variation called Switch Plate and on the product displays it is showing Product Name on the title I installed from the 2.0 version of Commerce Kickstart it only shows on my product not on the 2 generated products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to admin/structure/types, and click "Manage display" for your content type, which is a product display for your new product variation.
Choose the "Product list" display, and make sure the title's format is set as *Default*.

Comment: Thank you that got it but I still had to look them but its gone now

Comment: I did this, however I am no longer able to link to product from product list. Is this normal?

Answer (score 0):

There is a recent issue on this on the [Commerce Kickstart's issue page](http://drupal.org/node/1885358); there is no solution yet, though.